# Why does lscm crash with on MacOS

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert

I just installed the RTC command line tools (v 6.0.4) on my Mac (MacOS Sierra 10.12.6) in hopes of using the `lscm` command to check out files from an RTC repository.  But `lscm login` (and many of the other `lscm` subcommands) fails with:

`Unexpected exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/team/process/common/advice/IProcessReport
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.cli.client.internal.subcommands.LoginCmd.run(LoginCmd.java:83)
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.cli.core.AbstractSubcommand.run(AbstractSubcommand.java:51)`

Anyone know what is going on?